# Java platform libraries Hashcode

Tags: java, hashcode

In Effective Java Item 9 (Always override `hashCode` when you override `equals`) where it says

> Many classes in the Java platform libraries, such as String,
>   Integer, and Date, include in their specifications the exact value
>   returned by their hashCode method as a function of the instance value.
>   This is generally not a good idea, as it severely limits your ability
>   to improve the hash function in future releases.

What does it mean ?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: It means that the Java sources are not always a model of good programming style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you can't rewrite the hash function in later versions of your code to have better hashing properties.  For example, the `String.hashCode()` function is fast...but not very good.  But it can't be changed anymore, because the hash code was specified and people have depended on that implementation in their own code.

Comment: What do you mean by, "because the hash code was specified and people have depended on that implementation in their own code"?

Is it like someone does this: int hash = string.hashCode()
And then later they do something stupid like assert(hash == 12345)
?

Comment: @Hiro2k - The API docs specify that `String.hashCode()` is computed by a specific formula. Client code is free to independently compute the hash code using that exact formula and assume it will be the same as that returned by `String.hashCode()`. This might seem perverse for pure Java code, but does make some sense with JNI. There are probably other cases where it would make sense to take advantage of the extra knowledge that the API specifies.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit why people think String.hashCode() is fast but not very good ? Does that mean the traditional way of calculating the hashcode by 31 is not good ?

Comment: There are a variety of important measures of hash functions that measure how good they are at spreading inputs evenly, such as the [avalanche property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect), at which the `java.lang.String` implementation doesn't do very well.